# TFS to VSTS synchronization

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

My source code is in TFS. I want to maintain replica in VSTS. So whenever i check-in that code from TFS its automatically updated in VSTS for CI&CD pipeline. IS it possible ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why not just use VSTS? What are you accomplishing by maintaining an on-prem server at that point?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Right now we do not want to disturb the current TFS CI and CD flow. We are planning to use the VSTS completely in the next year. I will be wonder if any sync tools fulfill my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Git you could sync source code from TFS to VSTS using **Git Tasks** that is available on the TFS/VSTS Marketplace. Have a look at https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.gittasks

/Per